# Invoke db function with Appfuse

Tags: appfuse

I'm working with Postgress and appfuse.
Unfortunately, documentation is all about dao and bean but nothing when you need to call a db function.

What is the best approach to do that?

I tryed to create a DbUtil class:

```
public class DbUtil extends HibernateDaoSupport {

    public DbUtil() {}
    public void runCommand() {
        getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback() {
        @Override
        public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
                session.createSQLQuery("select myfunction....");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and calling it from my controller:

```
dbUtil = new DbUtil();
dbUtil.runCommand();
```

give me a NullPointerException.
Probably I haven't already understood the appfuse philosophy...
Any help appreciated !

Thanks
Bye
Fred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure your DbUtil class as a Spring bean and inject it into your class using @Autowired. That way, the Hibernate session will be set properly.